# Editing downloaded file opened with "Open" instead of "Save"

Tags: microsoft-word, download, microsoft-edge

A friend of mine needed to download a file and then edit it. She downloaded it through Edge, the "Open" or "Save" prompt came up, she clicked "Open" and it automatically opened the file in Word 2016. She then made some changes to the file, clicked "Save" in Word and exited Word. Then she realised that the file isn't there, because she opened it with "Open" instead of "Save". Is there a way to retrieve this edited file or is it lost now?

Comment: If your friend saved it in word then that instance of it exists unless you mean the original document which doesn’t exist

Comment: She should have saved it to known location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on "open", Edge will download the file to a temporary folder. That folder is located at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_xxxxxxxxxxxxx\TempState\Downloads`
However when you close Edge all files in that folder are deleted and you won't be able to retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the friend closed the Edge too, guess there's no way to get that file then.

Comment: Well, you could try an undelete program but the chances of success are slim.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any documentation saying Edge deletes files in the `...\Tempstate\Downloads` folder upon closing? The files do seem to be deleted eventually, but it doesn't seem like it always happens as soon as the browser closes and I can't figure out the exact trigger.

Comment: In my testing today, it cleared all files in `...\TempState\Downloads` in every test I could think of, even files that I put in that folder on my own and which weren't even downloaded by Edge. Maybe a recent update changed the behavior, or maybe I'm just remembering wrong. It would still be nice to have some official documentation about it, but in any case it seems the new Edge matches Google Chrome's behavior of automatically putting everything in the Downloads folder and never cleaning up after itself. I can only hope this is a side-effect of moving to Chromium and won't be permanent.